# Select * vs specific columns & loading object properties

Tags: sql

I always thought SELECT * was bad and that you should always return only the columns you are going to use. One of the reasons for this is that the DB can return the result without hitting any tables if all the columns needed are in the index.

I have a factory class that loads the properties of a Product object. It loads all the properties everytime GetProduct is called etc.

Many of the pages won't be using all of the Product properties even though they will be loaded from the database because of the SELECT*.

Is there any design advice/guidelines on this?

Comment: Why did you tag this as [tag:c#]?  This is more of a SQL/query writing question.

Comment: If you store the primary key and any common/indexed fields on initialization, you could look at implementing lazy evaluation on the "other" properties. It should be an index seek (good & fast) since you'd have the PKs available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd definitely avoid `SELECT *`. Just retrieve the data you know you'll need. I'd prefer to write a dozen queries to the same table, where each one refers to just the few columns I need for a particular purpose, rather than write one query that retrieves all the columns and just use that everywhere.

Even if you know you need every column currently in a table, list each one explicitly. That way, if someone adds half a dozen more columns to the table in the future, all your old queries won't suddenly be retrieving more data than is needed.

Comment: The problem is that some pages use specific properties. So I'd have to remove the GetProduct method and add in a specific method that retrieves specific properties per page?

Ex:
GetProductForProductPage and GetProductForProductDetails page

Answer (score 3):

The trade-off here is between squeaking out every last bit of potential performance versus code maintainability.  There is no question that bringing back columns you won't use wastes some CPU cycles.  The question becomes: how many?  Then you have to consider what is more expensive, your wasted CPU cycles or your programmers' time for building and maintaining the code?

If you are working on a system with huge performance requirements then it may very well pay to optimize your ORM / factory code.  On the other hand, if you're building a departmental line of business app and you've got scores or hundreds of ORM classes, maybe you are better off keeping it simple for the programmers (and the people who have to pay for them) and stop worrying about a few cycles.  This becomes even more the case if you use a framework that scaffolds up most of your ORM code for you with code generation - like Entity Framework (or many others)...

If you are building your system without the use of any kind of code generating framework, and if your data access layer is pretty close to bare metal SQL then only bringing back what you need is good advice.  If you are building an app that is going to be used by thousands or millions of people simultaneously, then by all means tune your SQL from the outset.  If, on the other hand, you work in a shop that uses ORM frameworks and RAD or agile then writing dozens of SQLs is counter productive.